# Cinelerra GG lv2 support

Tags: plugins, video-editor, cinelerra

I was keen to try out the new .lv2 support in Cinelerra GG but since updating my preferences to direct it to my lv2 folder the programme won't launch. Looking at the following it looks to me as though Ardour's a-comp plugin might be the source of the problem:

`init plugin index: /usr/lib/cin/plugins
init lv2 index:
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Analyzer
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/BassEnhancer
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/CompensationDelay
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Compressor
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Crusher
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Deesser
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Emphasis
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/EnvelopeFilter
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Equalizer12Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Equalizer30Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Equalizer5Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Equalizer8Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Exciter
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Filter
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Filterclavier
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Flanger
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Fluidsynth
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Gate
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/HaasEnhancer
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Limiter
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MonoCompressor
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MonoInput
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Monosynth
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MultiChorus
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MultiSpread
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MultibandCompressor
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MultibandEnhancer
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MultibandGate
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/MultibandLimiter
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Organ
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Phaser
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Pitch
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Pulsator
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Reverb
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/ReverseDelay
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/RingModulator
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/RotarySpeaker
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Saturator
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/SidechainCompressor
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/SidechainGate
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/SidechainLimiter
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/StereoTools
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/TapeSimulator
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/TransientDesigner
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/VintageDelay
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Vinyl
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Vocoder
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/Wavetable
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/XOver2Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/XOver3Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/XOver4Band
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/eq12
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/eq5
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/eq8
LOAD: http://calf.sourceforge.net/plugins/mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/balance
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/convoLV2#Mono
Buffer size: 4096
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/convoLV2#MonoToStereo
Buffer size: 4096
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/convoLV2#Stereo
Buffer size: 4096
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/fat1
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/fil4#mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/fil4#stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/gmsynth
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#BBCM6
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#BBCmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#BBCstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#COR
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#DINmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#DINstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#EBUmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#EBUr128
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#EBUstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#K12mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#K12stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#K14mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#K14stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#K20mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#K20stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#NORmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#NORstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#SigDistHist
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#TPnRMSmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#TPnRMSstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#VUmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#VUstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#bitmeter
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#dBTPmono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#dBTPstereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#dr14mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#dr14stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#goniometer
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#phasewheel
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#spectr30mono
spectr.lv2: band f: 20158.74Hz (17824.72Hz -> 22492.75Hz) exceeds nysquist (44100/2)
spectr.lv2: shifted to f:19937.36Hz (17824.72Hz -> 22050.00Hz)
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#spectr30stereo
spectr.lv2: band f: 20158.74Hz (17824.72Hz -> 22492.75Hz) exceeds nysquist (44100/2)
spectr.lv2: shifted to f:19937.36Hz (17824.72Hz -> 22050.00Hz)
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#stereoscope
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#surround3
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#surround4
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#surround5
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/meters#surround8
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/mixtri#lv2
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/nodelay
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/onsettrigger#bassdrum_mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/onsettrigger#bassdrum_stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/sisco#3chan
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/sisco#4chan
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/sisco#Mono
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/sisco#Stereo
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/stepseq#s8n8
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/stereoroute
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/testsignal
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/tuna#one
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/tuna#two
LOAD: http://gareus.org/oss/lv2/xfade
LOAD: https://community.ardour.org/node/7596
LOAD: urn:ardour:a-comp
** segv at 0x7ff70cacfe48 in pid 2706, tid 2706
writing debug data to /tmp/cinelerra_2706.dmp
** dump complete
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Can anyone advise me how I might troubleshoot this problem, so that I can at least run Cinelerra again, but ideally with lv2 support as that was what grabbed my interest in the first place?

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.  I work with Good Guy on cinelerra-gg.  You are right about the plugin being Ardour -- the reason the terminal shows all of the LV2 plugins when they load is because there are so many of them and a lot of them are not compiled to run on a specific distro.  You can solve your problem in a couple of different ways.

1) restrict the plugins that are loaded with Cinelerra-gg by listing only ones that work well on your distro; for example as follows before you start cinelerra
  export LV2_PATH=/tmp/j/balance.lv2/usr/local/lib/lv2/:/usr/local/lv2
you will probably want to set this back for DAWs.
OR
2) in Settings->Preferences, Interface tab, set your "Default LV2 path" and click on the line above to reload your plugins.
OR
3) edit the file in your cinelerra path named "lv2_blacklist.txt" to include your lv2 plugins that SEGV or will not load.  You will need to reload plugin index and restart.

This information is documented in Features5.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will have a go at this! :)
Any chance you might consider adding an opacity or intensity value to the apply LUT effect?
Thank you for the work you and GG do on this project!